# prolog factorial recursion giving expression as output

Tags: recursion, prolog, factorial

I've written a prlog recursive factorial clause which is:

```
factorial(X,Y):-
      (X>1)
   -> factorial(X-1,X*Y)
   ;  write(Y).
```

The problem is, for any valid call[for example,  factorial(5,1). ], it is giving an expression rather than a value[(5-1-1-1)* ((5-1-1)* ((5-1)* (5*1)))]. How can I get a value rather than an expression.

Comment: check out [is/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2) predicate.

Comment: @WillNess Can you elaborate on how can I use it in my code? I'm new in prolog.

Comment: `A is 1+2, ....`.

Comment: Prolog does *not* evaluate expressions in line as you are attempting to do with `factorial(X-1, X*Y)`. They are just terms to Prolog unless you explicitly evaluate them with `is/2`, one of the numeric comparative operators (such as `>/2`) or with CLP(FD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @lurker is a bit simplistic. Comparison operators *do* evaluate expressions. So, your code could be made to work:

```
factorial(X,Y):- X>1 -> factorial(X-1,F), Y=X*F ; Y=1.

?- factorial(5,X),F is X.
X = 5*((5-1)*((5-1-1)*((5-1-1-1)*1))),
F = 120.
```

Comment: @WillNess: yeah, too tired!